# add event which is geneerated by jquery append method

Tags: jquery, events, binding, event-handling, append

I have a question about attach event.

First: after document is ready, I made ajax and success

Second: after ajax success, I append some code to body tag

Third: I'd like to attach event which is created at Second.

Below is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<!--jquery, cookie import-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/phone',
      type:'post',
      success:function(){
        $('body').append('<div class="test">hi</div>')
      }
    })
  })

  $('.test').on('click',example)
  function example(){
    alert('success');
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

after I run this, when I click the div, no alert popup..

IS there anyone who can explain why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes  - it's logical. You're binding the event to an element that doesn't yet exist. It's not future-aware; it won't attach itself to any elements that turn up in the future that match the selector.

Instead, [delegate the event](https://medium.com/@bretdoucette/part-4-what-is-event-delegation-in-javascript-f5c8c0de2983). This is good practice generally for events except in simple cases involving single elements or elements you know for sure exist at the time of binding the event.

```
$('body').on('click', '.test', example);
function example() {
    alert('success');
}
```